# Product changes when switching language on product view

Tags: product, url, url-rewrite, language, products-view

I'm at the brink of finishing a major project with magento here. However, there's this one really weird bug left I need to fix.
My verdict:

- I am on a product view page, currently on the english version
- I hover on the language switch button and see, that the link is exactly the same as the current sites link, only with the extra "fromstoreid-tostoreen" appended.
- I click on the button to change the language, to Indonesian that is
- Now, my store is viewed on Indonesian, BUT, it is a completely different product than that shown on the previous language(english)
- When I switch back to english, again, a different product is shown, even different than when I first viewed it on the english store, it kind of redirects me to random products without a pattern

Info: it only happens with products that has numbers in it(the entity_id at the end of the link), but works perfectly for number-less links
I am using magento 1.9.1

Comment: are you sure it's not the same product but with a different store view, as you may know, products can be different on a store view level.

Comment: @JulienLachal Hi Julien, yeah, I'm pretty sure that it is not the same product. Another anomaly I stumbled on was that the same product, can have different link when viewed on a different language. For example, If i was on the EN store, the link of product #3456 would be www.somelink.com/store/slug-3456.html BUT when I were to switch language, the very same product would show a different link, say: www.somelink.com/store/slug-4094.html

Comment: Have you tried reindexing them? Clearing Magento's cahe and all that jazz?